# How to fix bluetooth issues on Catalina 10.15.4?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

Before Mojave, bluetooth on my MacBook Pro 11,3 worked great - I could connect to whatever I liked and everything "just worked".

After upgrading to Mojave - I couldn't connect to any device from my MacBook Pro except my iPhone (I could use it as a hotspot / use the internet connection), but even my Magic Keyboard 2 wouldn't work with my MacBook Pro, unless it was connected via USB. (Magic Keyboard works fine with iPhone and iPad)

I tried the following:

1. Reinstalling Mac OS
2. Resetting the Bluetooth Module
3. Resetting PRAM, SMC etc
4. Removing all Bluetooth devices
5. Deleting the bluetooth plist file.

The above steps didn't make any noticeable difference.
After updating to Catalina... still no difference...

But after updating to 10.15.4, now my Magic Keyboard works with my MacBook Pro! But my Mac can't discover some other non-apple devices, for example, it can't see my bluetooth speakers (which it worked fine with before Mojave, and my iPhone and iPad can see the speakers...)

Clearly its not a hardware issue, since it works fine with my iPhone, iPad and Keyboard... clearly its not the fault of my speakers, since no "software" has changed on my speakers, and everything else can connect to them..... clearly its a software issue, since the behavior of my Mac changed only with OS updates.....

How to fix this once and for all?

Comment: Could you temporarily turn Wi-Fi off on your MacBook Pro and check if check the Bluetooth pairing with your speakers? Mind to make your speakers visibles on Bluetooth to be able to pair again.

Comment: Could you check that nothing else is now connected to your speakers. This might be tedious since you will have to go on any iPhone, iPad… and check `Bluetooth > xxx_Speakers > ℹ️ > Disconnect`

Comment: @dan nothing else is connected to it

Comment: Mac still can’t see the speakers...

Comment: Could you open `Bluetooth Preferences...`, turn `Bluetooth` off.
[return]Then open a `Terminal`, and run inside the command: `tail -f /var/log/wifi.log`.
[return]Then turn `Bluetooth` on , and let `Bluetooth Preferences...` hunt for 1 minute for other devices.
[return]Then make a copy of what was output in your `Terminal` window and add it to your original question as code ( `{}` ).

Comment: @dan I didn't do what you mentioned in the last message. For no reason at all, it started working... after over a year of being unable to connect. No explanation at all.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to signal this positive change. Did you restart your Mac or your speakers? Did you start 2 bluetooth equipment at the same time?

Comment: @dan actually my comment was premature. It seems that when both my monitors are connected to my MacBook Pro, the Bluetooth doesn’t work properly again. I cannot connect to my magic keyboard or my speakers, only my iPhone

Comment: When connected to my monitors, I use Ethernet, and wifi is switched off.

Comment: How are your monitors connected? Describe ports, cable paths and intermediate hardware.

Comment: @dan one monitor is connected via the thunderbolt port (thunderbolt to hdmi cable), the other monitor via the Macbook Pros hdmi port with an ordinary hdmi cable. There is no intermediate hardware. I also connect a usb cable from each USB port of my MacBook Pro to each monitor so I can use the USB ports on the monitor.

Comment: Some cables and some hardware may cause interferences because they are not correctly armored. I will suggest you to proceed through a trial and error check. Disconnect one kind of cable at a time, check if you can connect to your speakers (because the hardest to reach is a good reference point). Then don't reconnect this cable and proceed with the next one.